# Let $S$ be the set of all infinite sequences of positive integers $k_1, k_2,..., k_n...$ which are strictly increasing. The cardinal number $|S| = c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $S$ be the set of all infinite sequences of positive integers

$k_1, k_2,..., k_n,...$ which are strictly increasing.

The following "proof" of the statement that the cardinal number  $|S| = c$ is incorrectly done by me(as my teacher told):

**Proof :** Identify each element of $S$ as a strictly increasing function $f : \mathbb{P} \to \mathbb{P}$ with $f(n) = k_n$.

For each $f\in S$, define

$$ a_n =  1 \ \text{if} \ n \in Im(f)  \\
       =  0  \ \text{if} \ n \notin Im(f)$$

for $n \in \mathbb{P}$.

This defines a function : $ \phi : S \to (0, 1]$ with

$\phi(f) = a_1a_2a_3...a_n...$

the binary representation of a real number in the interval $(0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Because it is a bijection, it follows that $|S| = |(0, 1]] = c$.

**My question :** help me find the error in the above incorrect "proof" and modify it, so that the same idea using the binary representation of decimal real numbers proves the statement.

Comment: Maybe spell out why $\phi$ is a bijection. Nevertheless your proof seems fine to me.

Comment: @Berci he said that's it's certainly incorrect.

Comment: Well, it's not incorrect, but just not justified. The construction works, it's just that you haven't showed why it works (well, not in a detailed way, at least).

Comment: Note that equalities like  $0.10000...=0.0111111....$ and the fact that all elements of $S$ are infinite imply that the map is surjective.

Comment: Do I just need to say that a finite decimal $0.23$ can be expressed as $0.23$ or $0.22999...$. For this case we need to stick to the reccuring decimal representation by using $9$'s only. Also shouldn't $\phi(f) = 0.a_1a_2...a_n...$???

Comment: @Rene I just modified my method to tackle it. Now do you think it's okay?

Comment: @Rene is it possible to find such $f\in S$ such that $\phi(f) = 0.10000000...$? I don't know why but that seems impossible to me. For that to happen $n \notin Im(f)$ for any $n \ge 2$. Is it possible for it to happen?

Comment: Because $S$ consists of strictly increasing infinite sequences, for any $f \in S, \phi(f)$ cannot have a last non-zero bit. There must be some higher indexed bit that is also not $0$. Otherwise $f$ would be a finite sequence.